# Реализация быстрой сортировки выбрасывает IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, алгоритм

Совсем не давно начал изучения Python. Еще, можно сказать, ничего не знаю о нем. Решил написать быструю сортировку, вот код:

```
def quickSort(ar, left, right):
    key = ar[int((left + right) / 2)]
    l = left
    r = right
    while left <= right:
        while ar[left] < key:
            left += 1
        while ar[right] > key:
            right -= 1
        if left <= right:
            ar[left], ar[right] = ar[right], ar[left]
            left, right = left + 1, right - 1
    if(l < right):
        quickSort(ar, l, right)
    if(left < right):
        quickSort(ar, left, r)
    return ar

array = [34, 6, 2, 6, 5, 4, 0, 6, 1, 9, 2, 5]
print(quickSort(array, 0, len(array) - 1))
```

Результат:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vova/PycharmProjects/sorting/main.py", line 47, in <module>
print(quickSort(array, 0, 12))
File "/home/vova/PycharmProjects/sorting/main.py", line 35, in quickSort
while ar[right] > key:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Долго долбался, но так и не понял, почему получается выход за пределы массива... Не останавился на этом, переписал алгоритм на известный мне С++, и, о чудо, все работает... Может быть, это какое-то скользкое место языка или особенность, или я что-то делаю не так. Надеюсь на чью-нибудь помощь.

Comment: `qsort = lambda L: qsort([x for x in L if x < L[0]]) + [x for x in L if x == L[0]] +  qsort([x for  x in L if L[0] < x]) if L else L`

Comment: и запусти это на 100 миллионов значений)

Comment: @user184868 это вы мне? Используйте @ синтаксис, если хотите чтобы уведомление о вашем комментарии пришло.¶ Комментарий иллюстрирует алгоритм быстрой сортировки. Рассматривайте это как псевдо-код. То что это *исполняемый* псевдо-код — это просто бонус Питона.¶ В реальном коде, стандартные средства следует использовать как правило: `L.sort()` Но это не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу.

Comment: у меня ваш код работает без проблем.

Comment: @Денис попробуйте [пустой список](https://ideone.com/ACbmz3) или [`[2,0,1]`](https://ideone.com/cAh2z3). Вот [на Cython \[наивная\] реализация алгоритма быстрой сортировки](https://gist.github.com/zed/1257360)

Answer (score 0):

В строках

```
while ar[left] < key:
    left += 1
while ar[right] > key:
    right -= 1
```

вы движетесь вправо и влево не ограничивая перемещения 0 и длинной массива. Возможно такое изменение поможет:

```
while ar[left] < key and left < len(ar) - 1:
    left += 1
while ar[right] > key and right >= 1:
    right -= 1
```

Comment: товарищ же сказал что "переписал алгоритм на известны мне С++ и о чудо все работает"
когда я писал квиксорт в том месте можно сразу сравнение  if left >= right  и выход.

Answer (score -2):

```
ar[left], ar[right] = ar[right], ar[left]
```

попробуй написать перестановку нормально через переменную 
а может и проще, в самом начале делай right-=1 если указываешь размер)

Comment: зачем перестановку через переменную? ТС правильно использует удобства питона.